# How to play audio on PowerPoint 2010 with Windows 7 (64 bit)?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, microsoft-powerpoint

I searched for a solution a long time to no avail, I hope someone here can help.

I'm working with PowerPoint 2010 on Windows 7. Both OS and Office are 64-bit. I try to insert audio to the presentation but for each format I try (including file from the clip art gallery), I get the following error:

```
"PowerPoint cannot insert a video from the selected file. Verify that the necessary 64-bit codec for this media format is installed, and then try again."
```

When I add a video file, the video is playing, but without any sound.

I downloaded [this](http://www.free-codecs.com/download/k-lite_codec_pack_64-bit.htm) codec, but still no sound, and the same error.

Any ideas what else can I try?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you notice that the error says that PP can't insert -video- from that file?  What steps are you taking to add audio, and what formats are you trying?

Comment: Yes, the error seems wrong, I'm adding audio, not video, still the error message is about video. I add as usual: Insert --> Audio --> Audio From File / Clip art audio.
I tried mp3, mp4, wav.